# I want to place created functions in the bash_profile so that they are available everytime I login

Tags: function

I am relatively new to Linux Ubuntu.  How do I place created functions in the bash_profile so that they are available every time I log in?

Comment: what sort of help do you need? Editing the file? writing the function? Also this might be better on a site such as superuser..